# Ubuntu Stuck Logging IN

Tags: login

Whenever I try to login to ubuntu I enter my password it just kinda stays there with that white loading circle right where I entered my password.

**EDIT:**
I can login through the command line but not through the GUI and I can login as guest.

Comment: Well, the loading circle only comes when you input an incorrect password, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login with command line and delete your `.gconf` directory. just type `rm ~/.gconf`

`.gconf` is used to store user preferences. Deletion this directory **will flush gconf caches and will apply your settings right away**.